# How do I get C# syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2010 for an asmx file with no code-behind?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asmx, syntax-highlighting, intellisense

Needing to have a quickly deployable .asmx web service, I followed the instructions for the question [How do I create an ASMX web service page without a code behind file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437674/how-do-i-create-an-asmx-web-service-page-without-a-code-behind-file/437697#comment14570540_437697) , but found myself without syntax highlighting or Intellisense.

How can I enable syntax highlighting and Intellisense for C# code written directly in a .asmx file, without a code-behind?

Comment: The answer is probably, "don't do that".

Comment: Needed to do it for quick deployment of a quick-and-dirty web service. Why do you think I shouldn't do it though..?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: Nope, no solution yet...